# Is using strtok() in two functions safe?

Tags: c

I'm using `strtok()` to parse a line into individual words and check them for something. If that thing is found, another function is called which must also use `strtok()`.

I know `strtok()` is not re-entrant. Does that mean that if I call it in the second function, my position in the string in the first function will be lost? If so, would using `strtok()` in the first function and `strtok_r()` in the second solve the problem? Is there another solution?

edit:
thanks. it is indeed not possible to use strtok in two functions but apparently strtok_r is not standard. redesign it is...

Comment: Always using strtok_r should be the safe way to go.

Comment: @mkiever I think it is very rare that you have multiple threads all using strtok? Why exactly is a non-standard function the way to go, when thread-safety isn't even needed? All you'll do is to slow down your program and make it non-portable.

Comment: @Lundin non-standard ? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html

Comment: @marcolz Yes, it is not part of the C language and absent from the C standard.

Comment: @Lundin Like for instance gets() is? Why hold on to foot-shooting relics like strtok() when in practice there is always a better alternative available?

Comment: @marcolz There is no function called `gets` in C. It was made obsolete 17 years ago and removed entirely from the language 5 years ago. Also I don't program for POSIX operative systems at all, so `strtok_r` isn't even available.

Comment: @marcolz: Because the exact level of portability matters. Sometimes POSIX just doesn't cut it. At least *mention* that it's POSIX, not plain ISO/IEC C, when you're recommending alternatives.

Comment: You could use the optional ISO C11 function [`strtok_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), which is re-entrant.   This function is optional because not all of the compiler/library vendors on the standards committee wanted to put the effort in to support it.

Comment: @M.M: it is sad to see the committee standardize new functions like `strtok_s` with some over engineering, instead of standardizing widely available and used functions like `strtok_r()`,  `strdup()`, `aprintf()`, etc.

Comment: @chqrlie no doubt the reasons were similar; one crowd wrote one version and another crowd wrote another version and they couldn't agree to use the other's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1 :

> does that mean that if i call it in the second function my position in the string in the first function will be lost?

A1 : Yes, it does. If you do that, then a new scanning sequence will be started with another string that you provided, and data for subsequent calls for your first string shall be lost.

Q2 :

> If so, would using strtok() in the first function and strtok_r() in the second solve the problem?

A2 : The better approach would be to rework your program design.

Q3 :

> Is there another solution?

A3 : If the cost of design changes is too high, I would suggest keeping a copy of first string and a pointer that contains last found token. This can allow you to continue from last position (by getting a start pointer with *strstr* for example) after you are done with your second string.

Answer (score 7):

Since `strtok` internally uses a global variable to store how far it had advanced in the string, intermingling calls to `strtok` will fail, just like you suspect. Your options are:

- switch to `strtok_r`, which has a similar API, but is not standard C (it is in POSIX, though);
- avoid `strtok` altogether in favor of some other function that doesn't carry hidden global state, such as [`strsep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) (also non-standard);
- make sure your first function fully exhausts `strtok` before calling another function that can call `strtok`.

All in all, `strtok` is a function best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The library function `strtok` uses an internal static state for the current parsing position:

- when called with strings, it starts a new parse,
- when called with `NULL` as the first argument, it uses its internal state.

If you directly or indirectly call `strtok` from your parse loop, the internal state will be updated and the call with `NULL` from the outer scope will not continue from the previous state, possibly invoking undefined behavior.

Posix function `strtok_r` takes an explicit state argument, so it can be used in nested contexts.  If this function is available on your system, use it in all places where you use `strtok`.  Alternatiely, you could a different method with `strchr()` or `strcspn()`.

`strtok_r` is standardized in Posix. Depending on your target system, it may or may not be available.  MacOS and most Unix systems are Posix compliant. Windows might have it under a different name. If it is not available, you can redefine it in your program and conditionally compile it.

Here is a simple implementation you ca use:

```
char *strtok_r(char *s, const char *delim, char **context) {
    char *token = NULL;

    if (s == NULL)
        s = *context;

    /* skip initial delimiters */
    s += strspn(s, delim);
    if (*s != '\0') {
        /* we have a token */
        token = s;
        /* skip the token */
        s += strcspn(s, delim);
        if (*s != '\0') {
            /* cut the string to terminate the token */
            *s++ = '\0';
        }
    }
    *context = s;
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok website:

> Each call to strtok modifies a static variable: is not thread safe.

So yes you can't call this function from two different functions at the same time (threading) nor you can't call it like the following:

```
char input[] = "something that needs to be tokenize";
char *token = strtok(input, " ");
while(token) {
    puts(token);
    anotherfunction();
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

void anotherfunction()
{
   char input[] = "another string needs to be tokenize";  
   char *tok = strtok(input, " ");
   while(tok) {
      puts(tok);
      tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
}
```